# What does "$:$" mean in "$\;A_x : A_b = x^2 : h^2\;$"?

Tags: geometry, notation

In the FE handbook, on page 25, there's an equation for a right circular cone defined as the cross-sectional area of the cone varies with the square of the distance from the apex. The equation reads: 
$$A_x:A_b=x^2:h^2$$
What is the colon operator? Lindeburg solves this for $A_b$ by showing:
$$A_b=\frac{h^2A_x}{x^2}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is just what you use for ratios , $a:b$ means "a is to b".you can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology).

Alternatively you can write it as :

$$\dfrac{A_x}{A_b}=\dfrac{x^2}{h^2}\implies A_b =\dfrac{h^2\cdot A_x}{x^2}$$